# Changing the default driving view angle

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I've found that I prefer the close-up view when driving. Unfortunately, when I get in a car it always defaults to the next furthest out. I looked in the settings but couldn't find anything to change it.

Is there some way to change this default, or am I going to have to choose between changing the view each time I get in the car or just sticking to the one it gives me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that GTA's actually being a bit clever with this. After changing the angle a few times when getting in the car it seems to have gotten the message and set it as the default. So for anyone else having this problem, just keep insisting on the angle you want and it'll do it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

On both the PS and the Xbox, simply clicking the select button will change your camera view. You can also open the menu, go to settings, then display, and there should be a setting for vehicle camera height.

Comment: Do it in singleplayer, some settings are locked from there.

Comment: I'm aware of the setting for camera height- that's different to the camera view thing. I'll give singleplayer a go as soon as I get home.

Comment: I had a look in the singleplayer settings and the options are the same. While there is the aforementioned camera height option, it doesn't look like there's one for the view.